# Quickest way to insert dataframe into a SQL server from Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I have a dataframe with 1883010 rows.
Wrote the below snippet to insert the dataframe into the SQL server as:

```
import pandas as pd 
import pymssql

df_MthProd= df_MthProd.where((pd.notnull(df_MthProd)), None)  #convert nan values to NULL

df_Tuple = list(df_MthProd.itertuples(index=False, name=None)) #convert to tuples
my_query_syntax = """ INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_TEST]
           (
           [col1]
           ,[col2]
           ,[col3]
           ,[col4]
           ,[col5]
           ,[col6]
           ,[col7]
           ,[col8]
           ,[col9]
           ,[col10]
           ,[col11]
           ,[col12]
           ,[col13]
           ,[col14])
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s); """

conn = pymssql.connect(server = "SQLSERVER1", user = "USER1", password = "PASSWORD", database="DATABASE1")


with conn:
  with conn.cursor() as cur1:
    cur1.executemany(my_query_syntax, df_Tuple)
    conn.commit()
```

When I tried the same code for let's say 20 rows of data, it worked but for the entire dataframe, it has been running for 30 mins.
Is the above code not optimized for large datasets?

Comment: The `mysql` module already does the multiple-insert-at-once optimisation mentioned in the one duplicate, but it seems `pymssql` does not... Another possibility is to turn off indexing `ALTER INDEX ... DISABLE`, insert, then turn it back on `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD`, as mentioned in the other dupe. This way DB doesn't have to fiddle with the index after every insert.